# No kvm related group, but module exists

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, qemu

I have installed qemu from source and `/dev/kvm` and `kvm-intel` module exist. However, there is no `kvm` or `libvirt` group in order to add users.

```
$ grep virt /etc/group
$ grep kvm /etc/group
$
$ ls -l /dev/kvm
crw-rw----+ 1 root root 10, 232 ژوئن  20 12:13 /dev/kvm
$ lsmod | grep kvm
kvm_intel             217088  0
kvm                   598016  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
$ sudo modprobe kvm_intel
$
```

Currently, when the user wants to use -enable-kvm, he gets a permission denied error

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4000 -smp cores=2 -hda win7_64_snap_new.img -boot c -usbdevice tablet -enable-kvm
qemu-system-x86_64: -usbdevice tablet: '-usbdevice' is deprecated, please use '-device usb-...' instead
Could not access KVM kernel module: Permission denied
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize KVM: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s up to you to create the group and [set it up for KVM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#How_can_I_use_KVM_with_a_non-privileged_user.3F).

```
sudo addgroup kvm
```

will create the group,

```
sudo adduser ${USER} kvm
```

will add you to the group, and creating a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` containing

```
KERNEL=="kvm", GROUP="kvm", MODE="0660"
```

will ensure that members of the `kvm` group can access the KVM device node. (Name the file `40-permissions.rules` to match the linked instructions.)

The `udev` rules might not be taken into account unless you unload and reload the KVM modules, but you don’t need to do that:

```
sudo chown root:kvm /dev/kvm
sudo chmod 0660 /dev/kvm
```

will set the device node up appropriately for the time being.

Comment: If you have no command "addgroup", use the (more basic/lower level) command "groupadd" instead. Similarly, if you don't have "adduser", use "usermod -a -G kvm ${USER}". (Note that after these two comands, you will have to either logout and log back in, or issue the command "newgrp kvm" to actually be added to the kvm group.